# Trying to multiprocess a function requiring a list argument in python

Tags: python, mysql, multithreading

My problem is that I'm trying to pass a `list` as a variable to a function, and I'd like to mutlti-thread the function processing.  I can't seem to use `pool.map` because it only accepts iterables.  I can't seem to use `pool.apply` because it seems to block the pool while it works, so I don't really understand how it allow mutli-threading at all (admittedly, I don't seem to understand anything about multi-threading).  I tried `pool.apply_async`, but the program finishes in seconds, and only appears to process about 20000 total computations.  Here's some psuedo-code for it.

```
import MySQLdb
from multiprocessing import Pool

def some_math(x, y):
    f(x[1], x[2], y[1], y[2])
    return f

def distance(x):
    x_distances = []
    for y in all_y:
        distance = some_math(x, y)
        if distance > 1000000:
            continue
        else:
            x_distances.append(x[0], y[0],distance)
        mysql.executemany(sql_update, x_distances)
        mydb.commit()

all_x = []
all_y = []
sql_x = 'SELECT id, lat, lng FROM table'
sql_y = 'SELECT id, lat, lng FROM table'
sql_update = 'INSERT INTO distances (id_x, id_y, distance) VALUES (%s, %s, %S)'

cursor.execute(sql_x)
all_x = cursor.fetchall()

cursor.execute(sql_y)
all_y = cursor.fetchall()

p = Pool(4)
for x in all_x:
    p.apply_async(distance, x)
```

OR, if using map:

```
p = Pool(4)
for x in all_x:
    p.map(distance, x)
```

The error returns:
Processing A for distances...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./distance-house.py", line 94, in <module>
    p.map(range, row)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 251, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 558, in get
    raise self._value
TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I am trying to multi-thread a long computation - calculating a the distance between something like 10,000 points on a many-to-many basis.  Currently, the process is taking several days, and I figure that multiprocessing the results could really improve the efficiency.  I'm all ears for suggestions.

Comment: No - no manipulation.

Comment: Do you need to commit the distances within the loop? Would not it be more efficient to do it after the loop?

Comment: Yes, it would.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pool.map`:

```
p = Pool(4)
p.map(distance, all_x)
```

as per the first example in the [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html). It will do the iteration for you!

Comment: Sorry - I think that was a typo (I've edited my post to distance(x)).  In my many attempts to debug, I did that at one point (along with re-calculating all_y on every pass of distance(x)).  The problem with `pool.map` seems to be that x is not iterable, because it is a list x = ['id', 'lat', 'lng'] - am I still missing something?

Comment: Well, I am probably not the top expert, but this looks strange. Can you add your `map` code and the exact error to your question?

Comment: Also, debug your code and check the type of `all_x`, if you have not done it already. And try the usual loop to see if it works (not on all x's, just on the first few).

Comment: Type for all_x is `tuple`.

Comment: Thanks!  I should have known `all_x` was iterable when I was using it in a `for` loop... <sigh>.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Another way to Approach it is to pack your variables inside a tuble and unpack inside the function.
example:

```
def Add(z):
  x,y = z
  return x + y

a = [ 0 , 1, 2, 3]
b = [ 5, 6, 7, 8]
ab = (a,b)

Add(ab)
```